# How to update date of multiple photos in Flickr?

Tags: flickr

I have uploaded 184 photos to Flickr, but the "date taken" of those photos are incorrect. I would like to batch update the dates instead of one by one. How can I do that in Flickr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date can be changed using the "Organizer". Do the following steps.

1. Access the Organizer from the "More" menu select "Organize"
2. Then add the photos which dates need to be changed by dragging them from the bottom to the area which says "Drag items here to edit them as a batch"
3. Then click the "Edit Date" button and set the date.